# Error When trying to run sparkling-shell on windows

Tags: apache-spark, h2o, sparkling-water

I have installed sparkling water for apache spark 3.2.3 and trying to run sparkling-shell command on cmd

I also installed "spark3.2.3-bin-hadoop3.2" from the apache spark archive which is compatible with h2o sparkling water  Version 3.40.0.4-1-3.2.

now after setting up all my environment variables, when i run the command "sparkling-shell", im getting this error :

**You are trying to use Sparkling Water built for Spark 3.2.3, but your %SPARK_HOME(=C:\Program Files\spark-3.2.3-bin-hadoop3.2) property points to Spark of version ~-5. Please ensure correct Spark is provided and re-run Sparkling Water.**

As you can see, it is showing "**Sparkling Water built for Spark 3.2.3"** and  **"%SPARK_HOME(=C:\Program Files\spark-3.2.3-bin-hadoop3.2)",** where i have also installed spark 3.2.3 only.

so, how do I resolve this???